# Conditionally sum values in a list of tuples

Tags: c#, linq

Hello what I'm trying to do is hopefully simple, I have a `List<tuple>(string, decimal)` and I'm trying to grab the sum of the decimal values if there are two similar strings.

My list contains the values:

- ("q", .5)
- ("w", 1.5)
- ("e", .7)
- ("r", .8)
- ("q", .5)

The sum of all the values would therefore be `.5 + 1.5 + .7 + .8 + .5 = 4.0`.

I assume the algorithm would be something like this:

```
newlist.select(item1 , item2).where(get the sum of first "q" up to the next "q" in list)
```

As for existing code, I don't have much only the declaration of the list and it's values.

**I want the sum between 'q' and 'q' + the values of 'q' and 'q', not just in-between, the answer should be '4' and not 3, I want everything between q and q including q's values, thank you.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on whether or not you want to sum only values for `q` or if you want to sum values between occurrences of `q`.  Can you update your question to explicitly define what you expect the output to be?

Comment: sum of values between q and q, and both q values, I have a list that has a lot of 'q''s with multiple values in between

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use simple `Linq` extensions, [`SkipWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
List<Tuple<string,double>> items = new List<Tuple<string,double>>() 
{ 
    new Tuple<string,double>("q", .5),  
    new Tuple<string,double>("w", 1.5), 
    new Tuple<string,double>("e", .7), 
    new Tuple<string,double>("r", .8), 
    new Tuple<string,double>("q", .5)
};


var sumvalue = items.Sum(c=>c.Item2); // Calculates sum of all values

var betweensum = items.SkipWhile(x=>x.Item1 == "q") // Skip until matching item1            
    .TakeWhile(x=>x.Item1 != "q") // take until matching item1
    .Sum(x=>x.Item2); // Sum
```

As asked in the comments, in case if you have multiple such sets and you want count in between those matching strings for multiple sets, do this.

```
    int gid = 0;
    items.Select(c => new { Tuple = c,  gid = c.Item1=="q"? ++gid : gid })
        .GroupBy(x=>x.gid)
        .Where(x=>x.Key%2==1)
        .SelectMany(x=>x.Skip(1))
        .Sum(x=>x.Tuple.Item2);
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O0WJ1g)

Comment: that's what I was looking for, thank you.  However, what if I have multiple q's? for example: "q" <-> "q" & "q" <->"q" & "q" <-> "q"? how do I get every single situation and put it on a new list?

Comment: I thought about this earlier, check updated answer :-).

Comment: tried the code and didn't get what I was looking for, can I add you on skype? I thought we can communicate faster over there than here.  here's .netFiddle where I add comments https://dotnetfiddle.net/yXZgXT

Comment: That's restricted on my work place, What is causing problem?.

Comment: I don't see any problem, I verified it is working fine [Check this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cwH2d2)

Comment: the program must: find 'q', add 'q's value (.5) and if <= 3.5, go to next index ('w', 1.5) and add .5 + 1.5 = 2 <= 3.5, continue... meanwhile, in a string List, 'q' is added, 'w' is added, each sum's string is added into a new list until <= 3.5, once it's done, repeat, find 'q' again and repeat the process, what this code does is get the sum of between 'q' 'q' which is a good start, but not complete yet, need help on that.  hmm do u have a little time so we can go to chat? I feel like we are almost done, just needs a few more tweaks, thanks

Comment: That's seems to be new addition, I suggest either edit this question or post new question with specific problem. Why I'm suggesting is, It may confuse people reaching this post having similar problem, so answer should (only) solve what referred in the question, shouldn't deviate to specifics. Hope you understand :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540606/conditionally-sum-values-in-a-list-of-tuples-using-linq-or-loops  here's the improved question, I know you can get this one, and thanks so much for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, please mark this as answer if this is answer to the question and helped you.

Comment: np, you earned it, please check my updated question please thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new IEnumerable extension to get all values between two conditions. Note that if there is no second occurrence of the condition an empty list is returned, this can be edited based on your requirements:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeBetween<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Func<T, bool> f)
    {
        bool first = false;
        List<T> ret = new List<T>();
        foreach (var item in e)
        {
            if(f(item) && !first)
            {
                first = true;
                ret.Add(item);
                continue;
            }

            if(first)
            {
                ret.Add(item);
                if(f(item))
                    return ret;
            }
        }
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Then it is just a matter of using this to get the sum:

```
var sum = list.TakeBetween(x => x.Item1 == "q").Sum(x => x.Item2);
```

Comment: Hello, can I please include the 'q's values too? the sum should be 4, and should be put in a new list, I will have multiple 'q's, for example: 'q' <stuff>'q' <more stuff>'q', etc.