# Conditionally sum values in a list of tuples using LINQ or Loops

Tags: c#

Hello what I'm trying to do is hopefully simple, I have a List(string, decimal) and I'm trying to get the sum of the first instance of 'q', add it's value and continue until <= 3.5 is false, it would look something like this:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
{

        var wordList = new List<string>();

        List<Tuple<string, double>> items = new List<Tuple<string, double>>()
{

new Tuple<string,double>("q", .5), //3.5 - .5 = 3
new Tuple<string,double>("w", 1.5), // 3 - 1.5 = 1.5
new Tuple<string,double>("e", .7), // .7 - 1.5 = .8
new Tuple<string,double>("r", .8), // .8 - .8 = 0
   /*
look for 'q', if found start at 'q', add values in Item2 until 
sum <= 3.5, put 'w', 'e', 'r' on a string List, once it stops, 
look for 'w' in the string list, if found --> //code, then, because 
the list is long and has many values, repeat the proces through the 
entire list, continuously looking for strings that meet the <= 3.5 sum 

Scenario example:

the first occurence of 'q' is in index 0, find it
add .5 and check if <= 3.5 is true, 
if so-continue, 'w', value is 1.5, add to sum (.5) = 2
2 <= 3.5, add 'w' into wordList, and repeat
'e', .7, .7 + 2.7 <= 3.5, add 'e' into wordList, continue...

after the conditions are met
wordList should have:

'w'
'e'
'r', check list:
'if any items in wordList contains 'w' --> code
else --> if contains 'e' --> //code
else --> if contains 'q' --> //code

'if 'q', 'w', and 'e' are not present...
keep checking and keep checking EVEN if
any were found, we want to go through the entire list
expecting to find some 

*/

new Tuple<string,double>("q", .5),
/* ok here's the next set, found this 'q', .5 <= 3.5, go to next
'w' 1.5 + .5 = 2 < =3.5, go to next
'q' .5 + 2 = 2.5 < 3.5, note that 'q' was added, but not the found 'q'
when searching for 'q', don't add it to wordlist if found, add subsequent
'q''s until <= 3.5

*/
new Tuple<string,double>("ba", .5),
new Tuple<string,double>("w", 1.5),
new Tuple<string,double>("q", .7),
new Tuple<string,double>("r", .8),
new Tuple<string,double>("ba", .5)


};

for (int i = 0; i < wordList.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (wordList[i])
            {
                case "w":
                    //code
                    break;

                case "e":
                    //code
                    break;

            }

        }
```

heres my previous post asking a similar question, don't mark as duplicate, I'm trying to delete my last similar post, this is the main post.
[Conditionally sum values in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538779/conditionally-sum-values-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: Your algorithm is very unclear to me. Maybe you can explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: in a tuple list, find 'q' and add it's value to a sum, if <= 3.5, go to next index 'w' and add it's sum into the previous sums, .5 + 1.5, if it's still <= 3.5, continue, once 3.5 is false, check wordlist for occurences of 'w' and 'e', if found, do code based on my switch statement, and repeat the process until list is fully searched, 'w' and 'e' might not be found but continue checking

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your wish correctly, try to add the following code into your main function:

```
counter = 3.5
foreach (Tuple<string,double> element in items)
{
      counter -= element[1];
      if (counter>=0) 
      {
            wordList.add(element[0]);
      } 
      else
      {
            break;
      }

}
```

Comment: yes! I'm feeling this answer, but what if I have 100 items in the list T_T, not only that, I want to evaluate this function before I go to the next check, //do code for this check, after that check again until list is fully searched, and thanks!